# Compare String into Another String inside a File

Tags: java, string, compare

I have tried the ".equals", ".contains", and "==" i still didn't get the result

```
 String pre = "0917";
        File file = new File("F:\\Eclipse\\Loading De Luna\\bin\\GlobePrefix.txt"); 

          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

          String prefix; 
          while ((prefix = br.readLine()) != null)
              if(prefix.equals(pre))
                  System.out.println("Found");
              else  System.out.println("Not Found");
```

The .txt file contains these strings:

```
0817 
0905 
0906 
0915 
0916 
0917 
0926 
0927 
0935 
0936 
0937 
0945 
0955 
0956 
0965
```

Comment: What's the content of the file, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Post the output you expect and the output you get. Explain why you expect that output.

Comment: "*i still didn't get the result*" - what result?

Comment: probably try `trim` like this `prefix.trim().equals(pre)`

Comment: Looks like there may be some blank spaces, try what Deadpool suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (prefix.trim().equals(pre))
    System.out.println("Found");
 else
    System.out.println("Not Found");`

Would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`prefix = br.readLine()`  will give you complete line not the word. It means you are comparing the entire line with the word. You have to check whether the required word exists in the line.

You have to modify like this

```
if(pre.indexOf(prefix.trim()) != -1)
             System.out.println("Found");
else  System.out.println("Not Found");
```